# It is possible to use Antialiasing in Multitexture mode?

Tags: game-engine

It is possible? or it is just a GLSL feature?

Comment: No, i mean in Blender Game engine.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure Blender's interface is set to "Blender Game" (usualy in the top of the blender window):
[image]

Then go to the "Render" settings in the properties panel. Under "Standalone Player" you can set the antialiasing samples:
[image]

If you also want to enable Antialiasing in the viewport, which also affects the embedded player, you have to set it in the user preferences. Press [Ctrl+Alt+U] to open the User Preferences window. Then go to System and set Multisample to your desired AA factor. 
You may have to restart blender for this setting to take effect.
[image]

Comment: I mean in the blender player and the embeded player, i already set the antialiasing samples for the player to 16 but it still looks aliased

Comment: Or do i need gpu? because i'm testing in a Intel atom laptop.

Comment: Look: http://imgbox.com/EwroAVw8

Comment: The AA settings of the embedded player are those of the normal viewport. You need to set them in the User Preferences and then restart Blender. The AA samples you have set in the linked image only affect the Standalone Player. Have you tried starting the Standalone Player? Does it have AA?

Comment: Yes, look: http://imgbox.com/IMRRiVKQ

Comment: I did a quick google search and it lookl like some Intel integrated graphics cards do not suppot Multisample Antialiasing. Maybe your card really can not render AA.

Comment: Well thanks, i consider this the final answer. Thanks for your help :)